# Can git diff include the latest author and revision date?

Tags: git, git-diff

When I merge branches, I frequently want to get a summary of all the file differences between the branches.

`git diff --stat -r branch1..branch2` works great for this, but I want to have author and date from the latest commit that touched that file as well. The output would look something like this:

```
ChangeColumns.cls                   | Author1 |  2/10/2015 | 95 ++++++++--------------
GiftApprovalController.cls          | Author2 |  2/11/2015 |  2 +-
MassRelationshipCreation.cls        | Author3 |  2/10/2015 |  2 +-
MultiselectedPicklist.cls           | Author4 |  2/08/2015 | 17 ++--
Paginator.cls                       | Author1 |  2/09/2015 | 11 ++-
PipelineManager.cls                 | Author4 |  2/10/2015 |  7 +-
TestSetupUtils.cls                  | Author4 |  2/08/2015 | 13 ++-
PipelineManager.page                | Author2 |  2/07/2015 |  5 +-
TestCoverageJsonData.resource       | Author1 |  2/10/2015 | 10 ++-
9 files changed, 78 insertions(+), 84 deletions(-)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `git diff` is pairwise: it compares the commit ID `branch1` (try `git rev-parse branch` to see that ID) with the commit ID `branch2`.  With that in mind, define "latest commit that touched [a] file": we know, based on the diff output, that branch1:ChangeColumn.cls and branch2:ChangeColumn.cls differ; do you want "which of these two ID-qualified files has a later time-stamp" or do you want something else, perhaps not even tied to ID1 and ID2 directly?

Comment: (Oops, make that: `git rev-parse branch1` and `git rev-parse branch2`, to see raw commit IDs.  The main reason to do this is to understand how branch names just name commit IDs; a secondary reason is that branch names resolve to *different* IDs over time, as you add new commits to those branches.)

Comment: @torek, That's a good point. What I am looking for is the date and author from the source branch. Basically what I would see in the first git log entry for that file.

Comment: This is still pretty tricky; [pratZ's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28441247/1256452) can get you a (or all) committer(s), especially if you add a path-name to the `git log` command (`git log A..B [other args] -- path`).  However, that may show too *much*, depending on what you want: suppose that in the `A..B` set, Bob commits a change to line 50, and then Cindy commits a second change that undoes Bob's change to line 50, so that `git diff` shows *no* change to line 50.  You'll get both Bob and Cindy here.  In any case you will need to write some code, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Though not exactly but `git log` should get you something closer to what you expect,

```
git log branch1..branch2 --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s"
```

This will only show you commit differences that `branch2` has but `branch1`doesn't. You will have to reverse it for the getting the commits present in `branch1` but not in `branch2`.

Add a `--stat` or `--name-only` to obtain file names

```
git log branch1..branch2 --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" --stat
```

Comment: --stat is pretty close to but it's commit oriented rather than file oriented which is what I am trying to get (I know, I am a bad gitter). 

I guess I could parse the output of git log but I'm hoping there's a nicer solution.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff` cannot do that. You can try one of the following:

- `git blame $branch $file` can show you who wrote lines in a file.
- `git show $commits` shows all changes in a commit or multiple commits (each commit separated).